# Passing CSRF token in Alamofire request parameters

Tags: ios, swift, http, httprequest, alamofire

I want to log a user on my website which has a CSRF token in his login form. I'm using Alamofire with Swift on IOS.

Here is the form code:

```
                   <form id="login-form" class="body" action="login" method="post">

                                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="username">Identifiant</label>
                                    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="password">Mot de passe</label>
                                    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control"
                                           required/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="footer">
                                                                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                                        <input type="hidden" id="csrf_token" name="_csrf"
                                               value="7cf3b95d-1310-4d00-b1b2-7040340b12e6"/>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
                                            Connexion
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

I created a function which returns the CSRF token. Then I call another function which logs the user with his credentials and the CSRF token.

Here is this function:

```
func login(token: String, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {

        let customerURL = "https://mywebsite.com/uaa/login"
        let user = "username"
        let password = "password"
        let parameters = [ "username" : user, "password" : password, "Authorization" : token]

        Alamofire.request(customerURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)

            .responseString { response in

                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    print("Validation Successful")
                    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                        print(JSON)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)

                }
        }
    }
```

But when I run my app, here is what I get:

```
{"timestamp":1510425797543,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.","path":"/uaa/login"}
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf'
```

I see you are using 'Authorization' name for parameter while the API compline that it reads it from '_csrf' change the name of the parameter from 'Authorization' to '_csrf'

from

```
let parameters = [ "username" : user, "password" : password, "Authorization" : token]
```

to

```
let parameters = [ "username" : user, "password" : password, "_csrf" : token]
```